# Use IMPORTDATA with URL and NOW()

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use IMPORTDATA in GoogleSheet with URL and time stamp

`=IMPORTDATA("https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt?t"=TEXT(NOW(),"ddmmyyyhhmmss"))`

> **ERROR** This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND() or RANDBETWEEN()

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The formula you quote has a semantic issue: the bit that looks like `?t"=TEXT(` should probably be like `?t=" & TEXT(`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual recipe to do that is to replace the `now()` in the formula with a reference to a cell, and fill that cell with a timestamp using a short script that runs on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

The recently introduced lambda functions let you mask volatile functions such as `now()` by wrapping them in what is in effect a semi-static closure, so something like this may work as well:

```
=let( 
  baseUrl, "https://www.amfiindia.com/spages/NAVAll.txt", 
  now, lambda(volatile, volatile)(now()), 
  postFix, "?t=" & text(now, "ddmmyyyhhmmss"), 
  refresh, F1, 
  importdata(baseUrl & postFix) 
)
```

The formula expects that you **Insert > Checkbox** in cell `F1`. Toggle the checkbox to recalculate the formula.